# deploying drupal on live server

Tags: drupal

I'm deploying drupal from localhost to a live server. But I can't access the pages:

i have http://localhost/site/admin, so i should have http://liverserver.com/site/admin, but it says the link does not exist.

I copied all the files to the live server.

Then, I made a copy of the database correctly, and changed the settings.php to the new mysql server.

The site shows up, but all my pages (clean urls) are not accessible, can't figure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you copied the .htaccess file? That's easy to miss, as many systems hide files with names that start with "." and it sounds like you don't have it.

FYI, until clean URLs are working, you can access admin pages by prefixing the path with "?q=", e.g. http://liverserver.com/?q=site/admin

Comment: That's correct! I'm quite new at drupal so i'm not used to some of its ways yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try Scott's tip above, looks like it is a clean URL problem.

Questions:

- Visiting the page http://liverserver.com/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls - does it say your server supports clean URL's or not?

If not
 - You may want to read the [extension documentation](http://drupal.org/node/15365) about this issue (as it is not a new one), paying particular emphasis on has mod_rewrite been installed on the web server (assuming apache)

Comment: Exactly, my server does not support. I'm on it!